# Has Midoriya's father ever appeared in the anime or in the series?

Tags: my-hero-academia

As far as I remember, Midoriya's father never appeared in the anime. What happened to him? Did he appear in the manga?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In Extra to Volume 11 of manga, in Midoriya's mother profile, it's said that her husband works overseas. This is the only information we are given about Midoriya's father in general; he is not shown or even mentioned anywhere else otherwise.

Comment: This does not actually answer the question on his appearing in the series or not even if it says where he is.

Comment: This answer gives the only information available about Midoriya's father in the entirety of manga. I've expanded answer to specify this more explicitly if it was not clear from the context.